# How to display content by qtranslate wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

To display all selected languages.

```
qtranxf_generateLanguageSelectCode();
```

To display page content

```
qtranxf_translate($post->post_content,false);
```

To display custome field content

```
if( qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'fr' ) echo $customMetaGroup['custom-field-english'];
```

Comment: Is this a question or answer? Please edit your post to better describe your question.

Comment: it is a answer.

Comment: Ok, how odd. You've posted a question though.